# Dados no datagrid duplicados

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6, expressões-lambda

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em WPF e quando preencho o datagrid via código o mesmo retorna o valor duplicado. Estou usando Entity Framework.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataLocal" Margin="10,111,11,10" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CidadeInicial}" Header="Cidade Inicial"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CidadeDestino}" Header="Cidade Destino"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Carga}" Header="Carga"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Kmrodado}" Header="KM Rodado"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Código C#

```
private void preencheDGV()
    {
        //this.DataContext = local.dadosLocais.Local;
        dataLocal.ItemsSource = local.dadosLocais.Select(x => new
        {
            x.ID,
            x.CidadeInicial,
            x.CidadeDestino,
            x.Carga,
            x.Kmrodado,
            x.Status
        }).ToList();
    }
```

Fora essa dúvida, tenho a seguinte questão: Como aplicar um AutoSize nas Colunas desse datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina a propriedade `AutoGenerateColumns` para `false`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataLocal" Margin="10,111,11,10" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CidadeInicial}" Header="Cidade Inicial"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CidadeDestino}" Header="Cidade Destino"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Carga}" Header="Carga"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Kmrodado}" Header="KM Rodado"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Sobre a outra questão, o correto é fazer em outra pergunta, mas basta definir a propriedade `ColumnWidth` como `*`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status" ColumnWidth="*">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Obrigado, resposta super completa. Ajudou bastante